# Optimal location of nucleation sites for voronoi partition of a square

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, computational-geometry

Do there exist algorithms to place n-points inside a square such that the Voronoi partition of the square (using these n-points as nucleation sites) minimizes the largest Voronoi cell in the sense that the maximum distance from one of these points to the vertices of the corresponding Voronoi cell is minimized? In other words, is there a way to place n seeds inside a square such that the maximum distance from any point in the square to the closest seed is minimized?